# How to show a hint while multiple ajax calls are running?

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento

I am working on a b2b version of a magento shop. 
So the customers see only a list of products and input-fields.
On change of an input field, an ajax-call ist set to update the cart.

Now I want to show a hint in the cart sidebar that the cart will be updated as long the ajax calls are running.

This is the ajax call:

```
$.ajax
({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: qty,
    success: function(response)
    {
        $('.block-cart').replaceWith($('.block-cart', response));
    }
});
```

and in my cart sidebar i've got a div which will be set to display: block while an ajax call is running.

I do this with the following code:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function()
{
    $('.hint').css({'display':'block'});
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function()
{
    $('.hint').css({'display':'none'});
});
```

But it does not work reliable. Sometimes the div is shown an sometimes not...

I hope you understand my problem and i make myself clear ;)

Thanks smo

---

**Update:**

i've got the start behavior to work. i've got a missing div in an other if statement. Now it works. but the `ajaxStop` is fired to early. even when some of the posts are running, the hint disapears. i have tried `ajaxComplete` with no other effect.

i'll stay tuned and let you guys up to date.

---

**Solved**

Hi there.

I have found a sollution, which works for me and i want to share it with you.

I just put the `ajax` into a queue. Here is the code.

```
$(document).queue(function()
{
    $('.hint').css({'display':'block'});

    $.ajax
    ({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: qty,
        success: function(response)
        {
            $('.block-cart').replaceWith($('.block-cart', response));
            $(document).dequeue();
        }
    });
});
```

Maybe this will help anyone else :)
Thanks so far,

smo

Comment: hmmm,can you add a jsfiddle . http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` are exactly what you need.  Can you explain why it's not reliable?  Incidentally, is it a typo that you never hide the hint when ajax calls stop? ;)

Comment: Which part isn't reliable, the stop or the start?

Comment: its the start part. i'll check the jsfiddle soon. Maybe i can add a link to a live demo soon.

Comment: thanks for the hint of the typo. In ajaxStop it truly has to be 'display':'none' but i got that right in my code.

Comment: unfortunately i am not able to get this in jsfiddle to work... @Archer: sometimes the hint was shown and sometimes not. even on the first ajax-call... unfortunately i am also unable to show you a live demo :( hope you guys could help me nevertheless. thanks so far!